# Server 12.04 LTS Desktop Environment install "Package xubuntu-desktop is not available, but is referred to by another package."

Tags: 12.04, server, xubuntu

I am trying to build the HP SDN VAN controller on Server 12.04 Precise but need a GUI to download the controller.

When i try to install a desktop i get the following (I have already done an `apt-get install update`)

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xubuntu-desktop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xubuntu-desktop' has no installation candidate
```

What is causing this issue and how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing XFCE using the command

`sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfdesktop4`

Run `apt-get update` beforehand.